# How to get selected radio and select box value at the same time, not individually

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a simple rails app which has a non-model form with a radio and a select box. I want the text to change based on a combination of radio and select.

On change, I managed to get the text from one or the other. But if I change the radio, the text I get from the select box is "undefined" and vice versa.

This is what I have:

view:

```
<%= form_tag "/tshirt/buy", role: "form", class: "tshirt_size_form" do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="genderRadio">Modelo:</label>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "male", checked: true) %>
            <%= label_tag(:gender_male, "Masculino") %>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "female") %>
            <%= label_tag(:gender_female, "Feminino") %>
        </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_tag :size, options_for_select([ "P", "M", "G", "GG"], "M"), class: "form-control tshirt_size_select" %>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
          <%= button_tag "comprar", type: "submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>    
    <div class="tshirt_size">
        <p>teste</p>
    </div>  
<% end %>
```

Coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
    $('.tshirt_size_select, input[name=gender]:radio').change ->
        size = $(this).closest('select').val()
        gender = $(this).closest('input[name=gender]:radio').val()
        $('.tshirt_size').text(gender + "_" + size)
```

PS: Yeah, my front-end chops are pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest` only traverses through ancestors, which means siblings are left out. You could do something like this:

```
jQuery ->
    $('.tshirt_size_select, input[name=gender]:radio').change ->
        size = $(this).closest("form").find('select').val()
        gender = $(this).closest("form").find('input[name=gender]:radio:checked').val()
        $('.tshirt_size').text(gender + "_" + size)
```

Which first traverses backwards to the form element, and then searches its children.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a lot (will accept in a few minutes, Stack Overflow won't allow me to accept so quickly